# Функция поиска элемента несколько раз отрабатывает верно, а затем начинает выдавать неверный результат

Tags: c++, бинарное-дерево, итераторы

Реализовал свое бинарное дерево с итератором. Первые 6 шагов итератора выполняются верно, но затем итератор шагает на месте (все время выводится 6ой элемент). Это происходит из-за того, что в определенный момент функция FindParent возвращает не предка элемента, а сам элемент. До этого функция отрабатывала верно. Не могу понять почему так и прошу помощи. Вот мой Next():

```
bool Next()
{
    if (currentptr == nullptr) // при первом вызове в сurrentptr записываю минимальный элемент
    {
        Node<T>* temp = root;
        while (temp->l != nullptr)
            temp = temp->l;
        currentptr = temp;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T>* temp = nullptr;
        Node<T>* parent = nullptr;
        while (true) 
        {
            if (currentptr->r != nullptr) //если у элемента есть правый потомок
            {
                parent = currentptr; //предок = текущий элемент
                temp = parent;
                do
                {
                    if (temp->r == nullptr)
                        break;
                    temp = temp->r;
                    while (temp->l != nullptr)
                        temp = temp->l;
                } while (true); 
                if (temp->r == nullptr)
                {
                    currentptr = temp;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else //если нет правого потомка
            {
                parent = FindParent(currentptr, root); //ищу родителя функцией FindParent
                if (parent->info < currentptr->info)
                    while (parent->info < currentptr->info)
                        parent = FindParent(parent, root);
                temp = parent;
                do
                {
                    if (temp->r == nullptr)
                        break;
                    temp = temp->r;
                    while (temp->l != nullptr)
                        temp = temp->l;
                } while (true);
                if (parent->info > temp->info)
                {
                    currentptr = temp;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentptr = parent;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
};
```

Сама функция FindParent():

```
Node<T>* FindParent(Node<T>* currentptr, Node<T>* root)
{
    if (root->info == currentptr->info && root->r != nullptr)
        return root->r;
    if (root->l != nullptr)
        if (root->l == currentptr)
            return root;
    if (root->r != nullptr)
        if (root->r == currentptr)
            return root;
    if (currentptr->info > root->info)
        FindParent(currentptr, root->r);
    if (currentptr->info < root->info)
        FindParent(currentptr, root->l);
}
```

Comment: А что это за комментарии "с точностью до наоборот"? "if (currentptr->r != nullptr) //если у элемента нет правого потомка"...

Comment: Опечатка. Всю ночь просто голову ломаю :)

Comment: Проблема была в опечатке?

Comment: Нет, это ведь всего лишь комментарий. Проблема актуальна.